# plugin get value from admin panel page

Tags: plugins

how to get values from a form(form is in admin panel page) and put that values in separate variables

```
<?php
    /*
        Plugin Name: calc plugin 
    */

    add_action('admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu');

    function my_plugin_menu() {
        add_options_page('My Plugin Options', 'My Plugin', 8, 'your-unique-identifier', 'my_plugin_options');
    }

    function my_plugin_options() {
        echo '<div class="wrap">';
        echo '<p>Enter Two locations </p>
              <form action="#" name="mapform" id="mapform">
                      Location A: <input type="text" name="A"><br />
                      Location B: <input type="text" name="B"><br />
                      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">
              </form>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the edit badge ... i am just a beginner to plugin development

Comment: @RutwickGangurde can you help em with this prob ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add an settings page, (or add options to and existing settings page) please use the [**settings api**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API):

- [`register_setting`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_setting)
- [`add_settings_section`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_section)

#### 1. Register your settings and add a section:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'plugin_admin_init');
function plugin_admin_init(){
     register_setting( 'wpse51578_options_group', 'my_option_field_name', 'wpse51578_validation_callback' );
     add_settings_section('wpse51578_main_id', 'My Main Settings', 'wpse51578_main_settings_cb', 'wpse51578_option_page');
}
```

The `'my_option_field_name'` int the `register_settings` is the name that the fields for your options should have: e.g.

```
        <input type="text" name="my_option_field name[A]"><br />
        <input type="text" name="my_option_field name[B]"><br />
```

The  `add_settings_section` registers a settings section for your page. You can of course, have multiple sections on a page.

#### 2. Output the form elements

The `wpse51578_main_settings_cb` callback function in `add_settings_section` is responsible for creating the output of that section. You can output the form elements in it (or user the api further with [`add_settings_field`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_field)). **No `form` tags should be used in this bit for this bit**. For example:

```
<?php
function wpse51578_main_settings_cb(){
      $my_options = get_option('wpse51578_options_group',array());
      $A = ( isset($my_options['A']) ? esc_html($my_options['A']) : 'default-for-a';
      $B = ( isset($my_options['B']) ? esc_html($my_options['B']) : 'default-for-b';
  ?>
       Location A <input type="text" value="<?php echo $A; ?>" name="my_option_field name[A]"><br />
       Location B <input type="text" value="<?php echo $B; ?>" name="my_option_field name[B]"><br />
  <?php
}
?>
```

#### 3. Output your settings page

When you added you added your page, you defined a callback to output the page contents. This is what that function should do, (using the `plugin_options_page` if you've given it in the question:

```
<?php
function plugin_options_page() {
?>
  <h2>My custom plugin</h2>
   Options relating to the Custom Plugin.

    <form action="options.php" method="post">
        <?php settings_fields('wpse51578_options_group'); ?>
        <?php do_settings_sections('wpse51578_option_page'); ?>

        <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Save Changes'); ?>" />
    </form>

<?php
}?>
```

#### 4. Validation

Now WordPress performs the nonce checks on your page, and handles (almost) all the processing of the forms. However - it needs you to do one thing - **validate**. When you register settings, you specify a validation callback function: `wpse51578_validation_callback` in this example.

This function gets passed an array of the values received from the form fields where the input name was `my_option_field_name` (as set also when you registered the settings). So for instance, you might expect the array:

```
 array(
     'A' => 'some-input', //value for A
     'B' => 'some-input-for b', //value for B
 );
```

Its job is to check that array contains 'correct' values (what that means depends on context: e.g. if its an e-mail field, is the value actually an e-mail address?). No sanitation is required here (but would be where-ever you output the data).

```
function wpse51578_validation_callback( $dirty ){
     //$dirty is what you receive from the form

     $clean = array();
     //Sanitize data and pass it to the $clean array

     return $clean;
 }
```

### Other Resources:

The best tutorial on using the settings API is probably: http://ottodestruct.com/blog/2009/wordpress-settings-api-tutorial/

*Please note that I've not tested the above, but it is correct in procedure, there just maybe typos or minor errors.*

Comment: This does not address the initial question which is how to retrieve the form values from the settings page into a  variable for a plugin.

Comment: @CareyEstes See part 2, you use `get_option()` to get the options from the database to a variable. WordPress handles collecting values from form and saving them to database. You filter/validate that array as per step 4.

Comment: You are correct sir

Answer (score 0):

Use the `init` action to handle the posted form. See the [codex for init](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) for details and example.

Edit:

```
<?php
/*
 Plugin Name: calc plugin 
*/

add_action('admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu');

function my_plugin_menu() {
    add_options_page('My Plugin Options', 'My Plugin', 'administrator', 'your-unique-identifier', 'my_plugin_options');
}

function my_plugin_options() { ?>
    <div class="wrap">';
        <p>Enter Two locations </p>
        <form name="mapform" id="mapform" method="post">
            Location A: <input type="text" name="A"><br />
            Location B: <input type="text" name="B"><br />
            <input type="submit" name="my_submit" value="Update">
        </form>
    </div>
<?php }

add_action('init', 'my_plugin_handler');
function my_plugin_handler(){
    if(isset($_POST['my_submit'])){
        $val_a = $_POST['A'];
        $val_b = $_POST['B'];

        echo $val_a.', '.$val_b;
    }
}
```

Comment: function process_post(){
 if(isset($_POST['unique_hidden_field'])) {
   // process $_POST data here
 }
}

unique_hidden_field , dies it mean that field should must be hidden?

Comment: Check my code. Not necessarily a hidden field, could be any form field.

Comment: yes the same thing i did. and it worked

Comment: new i want to take these two values and use them in google map to display two locations 

any idea ?

Comment: Then you may have to pass them to your javascript file. Read how to pass php variables to js files here: http://blog.rutwick.com/add-custom-javascript-to-your-wordpress-plugin-and-pass-php-variables-to-it

Comment: You should really use the settings api, see my answer above. For using setting variables in javascript you may want to search this site for similar questions. In short: [`wp_localise_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) :)

Comment: I've explained `wp_localize_script` in that post above! ;)